# Calling a Function in Parallel C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to call a function in parallel in C++, which waits for some time and performs some task. But I don't want the execution flow to wait for the function. I considered using pthread in a simple way but again, I have to wait till it joins back !

```
void A_Function()
{
/* Call a function which waits for some time and then perform some tasks */

/* Do not wait for the above function to return and continue performing the background tasks */
}
```

Note: If I do not perform the background tasks while calling the function in parallel then in the next cycle, the function doesn't give me correct output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `std::future`.

Comment: I don't understand the problem with using pthreads?

Comment: There is no problem using pthread if that solves the issue. I do not know much about pthreads. What I am doing now is to create a single thread and calling that function. But I have to do pthread_join() eventually right ? But I can not block the background tasks till pthread_join().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `std::future` to package a `std::async` task. Wait for the future at the head of your function to ensure that it's completed before the next iteration, since you stated that the next iteration depends on the execution of this background task.

In the example below, I make the background task a simple atomic increment of a counter, and the foreground task just returns the counter value. This is for illustrative purposes only!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>

class Foo {
 public:
  Foo() : counter_(0) {}

  std::pair<int, std::future<void>> a_function(std::future<void>& f) {
      // Ensure that the background task from the previous iteration
      // has completed
      f.wait();

      // Set the task for the next iteration
      std::future<void> fut = std::async(std::launch::async,
                                         &Foo::background_task, this);

      // Do some work
      int value = counter_.load();

      // Return the result and the future for the next iteration
      return std::make_pair(value, std::move(fut));
  }

  void background_task() {
      ++counter_;
  }

 private:
  std::atomic<int> counter_;
};

int main() {
    // Bootstrap the procedure with some empty task...
    std::future<void> bleak = std::async(std::launch::deferred, [](){});

    Foo foo;

    // Iterate...
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        // Call the function
        std::pair<int, std::future<void>> result = foo.a_function(bleak);
        // Set the future for the next iteration
        bleak = std::move(result.second);

        // Do something with the result
        std::cout << result.first << "\n";
    }
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80fb0dc0770099d5)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This is something new that I learnt. Unfortunately, I am forced to use a version which does not support <future> and <thread> (Only pthread is available) !!! I guess I have to find out another way :( :( :(

Comment: `std::future` is built on top of the platform's threading primitives. In your case, all you need is to check that the thread is done before you hit the next iteration, so the appropriate place for the [`pthread_join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) is at the top of the function, before doing calculations that rely on the work having been done. If you really want to fire-and-forget you can use [`pthread_detach`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_detach.html) which will never block, but you won't know when it's done.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I already solved the problem with pthread_detach. So far it works fine for me but also need to investigate all the corner cases. Thanks again !